# Which Ruby ORM supports PostgreSQL's Array Datatype?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, orm, activerecord, datamapper

I'm need to find a Ruby ORM (Active Record, Sequel, etc) that supports PostgreSQL's Array column datatype.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/arrays.html

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequel's `sql_subscript` is just for accessing values when querying, as you mentioned in an earlier comment.

Sequel doesn't have special support for database arrays other than that.  You can create arrays in create_table blocks:

```
DB.create_table do
  column :numbers, 'integer[]'
end
```

But that's not special support as Sequel is just passing the type through.  There's no built-in support for taking a ruby array and turning it into an PostgreSQL array when building a query, and there's also no support for turning the PostgreSQL array into a ruby array when retrieving (it'll be returned as a string).

That being said, Sequel is set up so that extensions for PostgreSQL's array and hstore types that offer full integration could be implemented with relative ease.  Someone has been working on support for hstore (I think it's finished or close to it, but I haven't reviewed it yet), and support for arrays should be similar to that.  It's likely that a future version of Sequel will ship with such support either by default or available as an official extension.

Comment: Answer should be updated now, I think: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3984710 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sequel supports this through the [`sql_subscript`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/SQL/SubscriptMethods.html#M000086) method on Symbols (and others).

Support was originally added in release 0.4.3 (2007-Dec) via `Symbol#|` and `Symbol#/`, but was changed to use the new method in release [2.12.0](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/release_notes/2_12_0_txt.html) (2009-Apr). Search the [CHANGELOG](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/CHANGELOG.html) for more mentions of improvements that have occurred over time.

Comment: How would you insert an ARRAY value into a new record with Sequel? sql_subscript looks like a read-only accessor

Comment: It's been a while since I played with that data type in Postgres, but, I think it's actually implemented as a string type. I used it for something and was massaging the value in my code, which I suspect was something I was doing in Perl via DBI. It's been several years and I don't have access to the code, so I can't look it up.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just ended up using the lower level 'pg' postgres driver directly.